# Word: Adding bells and whistles to a style

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word

I am preparing a book and wish each chapter title to be arranged in a certain way. Editing styles I see that I can set the font and quite a few other characteristics of the text, but I can not figure out how to actually *add* things like some carriage returns, or a horizontal rule etc. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add carrige returns as part of a style.  You can however set space before or space after the paragraph.  You can also add a bottom border to the paragraph to get a horizontal rule.

For both of these to work, the style will need to be a paragraph or a linked style, this won't work on a character style.

Edit the style you wish to use, in the bottom left of that dialog is a format button.
If you click that you get a list of options, for space before and after you need to pick paragraph. For the bottom border you need to pick Border.